# Cached autocomplete with Solr

Tags: jquery-ui, solr

I'm using jQuery-ui and Solr to make a neat search box with auto-complete. The query seems to work well but the results aren't actually displayed in my search box. Here is the code I'm using:

```
var cache = {};
$("#Keyword").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        if(term in cache) {
            response(cache[term]);
            return;
        }
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/terms/?terms=true&terms.fl=ctnt_val&wt=json&indent=on&terms.prefix=" + $("#Keyword").val(),
                request,
                function(data, status, xhr) {
                    cache[term] = data;
                    response(data);
        });
    }
});
```

So my best guess is that I'm not treating the returned values correctly. How could I make them appear properly underneath my search box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine what was wrong in my return function : I wasn't looping properly through the results. Best way is to use the map function to iterate through them.

```
$("#Keyword").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $query = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/terms/?jsoncallback=?&terms=true&terms.prefix=" + $("#Keyword").val();
        $.getJSON($query,
            request,
            function(data) {
                response($.map(data.terms.ctnt_val, function(item) {
                    return item;
                }));
            }
        );
    }
});
```